# how to generate a static html file from the output of a php script, using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I would like to generate a static html page from a url.I have created script file and save it.This code call script and write all content into new html file.

**php script fetch and savedata**

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("http://yourserver.com/site/categories.php");

file_put_contents("categories.html", $file);

?>
```

but could not understand how to use this php script in codeigniter

Comment: Can you post what you've tried with CodeIgnighter?  Are you sure you aren't running into permissions issues?  Have you checked the log files?

Comment: can you please read again my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function inside a desired controller. Let's say you want to save this file into a folder called `files` in the root (same level of `application`).

```
private function save_to_file($url, $file_name)
{
    if($file = file_get_contents($url))
    {
        $html_file_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../files') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name;
        file_put_contents($html_file_path, $file);
    }
}
```

Then, you would call this function (from another function in the same controller) by:

`$this->save_to_file("http://yourserver.com/site/categories.php", "categories.html");`

P.S.: The function is `private` so that you can not access that through url.